# Which data structure to use to pass pairs of values?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, data-structures

I need to store and pass around several paired objects:

1) An `NSString` of a filename such as "sprite.png"

2) `BOOL` value for whether or not that sprite should be animated.

So basically, I have a bunch of sprites, and each of them are either animated or not.

I thought I could use an `NSDictionary` to store everything, but I think using `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` as the key only allows you to have a single entry with that value.

What sort of structure is most appropriate to pass along that can satisfy my requirements?

Comment: Don't key by the boolean, then; key by the string.

Comment: NSDictionary is a closed hash (I believe) so either key by the string or create your own structure.

Comment: I think this is the same issue, if two key are @"NO", then the one added later does not get included into the NSDictionary. Should it be wrapped or something?

Comment: Not a string of the boolean, the string that represents the filename!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are saying is: I have sprites with a key @"spriteName" mapped to a value [NSNumber numberWithBool].

What are you going to be doing with this container? Like:
    Is it going to be holding a large number or is it small?(if its small like less then ten, an array, hash, tree, w.e is arguably irrelevant short term)
    Large number or unknown then it matters what you will be doing the most with it?
           -adding and removing a lot "NSSet"
           -looking individual things up a lot by a comparable key, "NSDictionary"
           -iterating through an entire list a lot "NSArray"
           Etc....

Etc... These are the kinds of questions you need to ask before you choose a container. There is a container programming guide on Apples resource site for developers, that more or less lays out which container is good for what.

Answer (score 4):

Since Objective-C is a strict superset of C you could use a C [struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29). Eg:

```
struct sSpriteDef
{
  BOOL isAnimated;
  NSString *name;
};

typedef struct sSpriteDef SpriteDef;
```

Comment: Just be aware that under ARC, you can't have object-valued members in your structs. This looks like a job for a custom object, or just a dictionary.

Comment: Never enabled ARC so far, now you gave me a reason to avoid using it completely. Actually I work mostly with Objective-C++, does this apply even to C++ classes? Just to know.

Comment: Even using C++ with STL has vastly more pros than cons for iOS games (that seems what the OP is doing). Especially with respect to performance. Which are pros if you are used to manage memory manually as in C++?

Comment: Strictly, @warrenm, you _can_ have object pointers in structs under ARC, you just have to promise the compiler that you'll manage their memory yourself by declaring them `__unsafe_unretained` and without using `retain` or `release`. Likely not worth it, but it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's gonna be a bag of pain when you switch from string constants to autoreleased objects like those returned from `stringWithFormat:`, etc. Your caveat is absolutely right, but `__unsafe_unretained` is better avoided in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Do a class:

```
@interface SpriteTuple : NSObject 

 @property (assign) BOOL shouldAnimate;
 @property (copy) NSString *filename; 

@end

@implementation

 @synthesize shouldAnimate, filename;

@end
```

You're done.  A somewhat more dynamic but a little less idiomatic way would be with individual hashes:

```
static NSString *image = @"ImageFileKey";
static NSString *shouldAnimate = @"ShouldAnimateKey";

@{ image: @"path/to/image.png";       shouldAnimate: @(YES) };
@{ image: @"path/to/secondimage.png"; shouldAnimate: @(NO) };
// ...
```

This is how someone from Python or Ruby might do this...

Comment: This is the most future-proof approach, in case the application eventually needs more data to be stored along with the sprites. Note, however, that with modern Objective-C, `@synthesize` is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, what you need is a way of representing a tuple, which you can use to associate a set of related values and pass together as an argument to methods, set as a property of an object etc. I have run into this question countless times in my own development. Early on, I would use an NSArray. So in your case, I would say:

```
NSArray *spriteTuple = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:someSpriteImageName,someBoolNSNumber,nil];
```

and unpack as:

```
NSString *name = [spriteTuple objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL animated = [[spriteTuple objectAtIndex:1] boolValue];
```

However, what would invariably happen over time is that the number of elements would increase as the project evolved, so what started as a pair would become a triplet, quadruplet, ... The above code would then become very prone to the error of reordering.

The answer that iLuvCapra provided as I was typing this is what I end up always doing now. Just make a  new class derived from NSObject and make the parameters its properties. Clean and extensible.